# Building a Word Cloud Jquery / HTML5 plugin

Tags: jquery, html, tag-cloud

I'm searching for a code that will help be build a tag cloud like [in this example](http://timc.idv.tw/wordcloud/#wikipedia.en%3awords). You can see that the words can even be embedded inside the spaces in the letters. The tag cloud should be based on weight, so words with higher weight will apear larger.

I want to create the exact same effect as in the link I've provided. I don't mind basing my plugin on an already existent plugin that does the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which part specifically do you need help with? Can you just use that cloud yourself? (I can't see a licence on the page so I expect not)

Comment: Being able to put words inside the space of other letters

Comment: Actually [the source is on github](https://github.com/timdream/wordcloud2.js) and it's MIT-licensed so youj can reuse it. I expect there's useful comments in there to understand it.

Comment: Excelelnt, what I needed. You can write the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code for that page is on GitHub:

- [the page](https://github.com/timdream/wordcloud)
- [JavaScript to render the cloud onto an HTML 5 canvas](https://github.com/timdream/wordcloud2.js)

Skimming the code it looks like it draws the text onto the canvas then reads back pixels from the canvas to find empty spaces to fill with more words.

Comment: @Rup , i m unable to find the wordcloud.js file. Can u please help me. Its Urgent

Comment: @Aamir Sorry, I don't know any more than is already here. Isn't it in the GitHub project in my second link?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very good one that I just used fo my project [jQCloud](http://mistic100.github.io/jQCloud/index.html)